# Bootstrap3 + IE9: Navbar not expanding

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Please see this website I'm developing for a client:

http://tinyurl.com/ot8fljg

The top menu is a bootstrap3 navbar. I've modified it with a small piece of js code, to make the submenu show on hover instead of click, like so:

```
$(function() {
        $('li.dropdown.hover').hover(
            function(e) { $(this).addClass('open'); },
            function(e) { $(this).removeClass('open'); }
        );
    });
```

However, it just won't show on IE9. I've been playing with IE's built-in developer tools for hours now, and I just can't seem to find the solution. Could anybody help me understand why it's only showing submenu borders on IE9?

Comment: Why do you wrap add class into function? `$('li.dropdown.hover').hover(
            $(this).addClass('open');`

Answer (score 1):

check whether your ie9 is in compatible view mode or not. so try this code: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`